# Blocking until one or multiple signals is emitted

Tags: c++, c++17, qt

I've written this little helper function, that will block the current thread until any of a given list of signals is emitted by an object or until an optional timeout is reached.
It can be used to synchronize network communication or the likes.

I'm not happy that you have to explicitly specify `std::tuple` on the call site (see usage below) but I didn't see any way that would still allow the trailing optional timeout argument.
Also I only use it in background threads that don't have any event loop yet, possibly this could mess with the main event loop if used in the main thread.

[Compiler explorer link](https://godbolt.org/z/fvoMPx9K7)

**Implementation**

```
/*!
 * \brief waitForSignals
 * waits until any of the given signals is emitted by the given sender or the timeout is reached (if given)
 * \param src
 * source object to monitor
 * \param sigs
 * the signals to listen for
 * \param timeoutMs
 * maximum time to listen for the signal before returning. if this is negative, no timeout is used
 * \return
 * true if one of the signals got emitted. false if the operation timed out
 */
template< typename Sender, typename ...Signal,
    std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_base_of_v<QObject, Sender> &&
        (sizeof...(Signal) > 0) &&
        (std::is_member_function_pointer_v<Signal> && ...) >* = nullptr >
bool waitForSignals(Sender *src, std::tuple<Signal...> sigs , int timeoutMs = -1)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    std::apply([&loop, src](auto... s){
        (QObject::connect(src, s, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit), ...);
    }, sigs);

    QTimer timer;
    bool aborted = false;
    if(timeoutMs >= 0)
    {
        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){ aborted = true; });
        QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
        timer.setSingleShot(true);
        timer.start(timeoutMs);
    }

    loop.exec();
    return timeoutMs < 0 || !aborted;
}
/*!
 * \brief waitForSignal
 * like \a waitForSignals but only waits for the one signal insead of a list
 * \sa waitForSignals
 */
template< typename Sender, typename Signal>
bool waitForSignal(Sender *src, Signal sig , int timeoutMs = -1)
{
    return waitForSignals(src, std::tuple{sig}, timeoutMs);
}
```

**Usage**

```
MyObject obj;
waitForSignal(&obj, &MyObject::mySignalOne);
waitForSignal(&obj, &MyObject::mySignalOne, 100);
waitForSignals(&obj, std::tuple{&MyObject::mySignalOne, &MyObject::mySignalTwo});
waitForSignals(&obj, std::tuple{&MyObject::mySignalOne, &MyObject::mySignalTwo}, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoiding the `std::tuple`

> I'm not happy that you have to explicitly specify `std::tuple` on the call site (see usage below) but I didn't see any way that would still allow the trailing optional timeout argument.

There is a way by converting the function to a `class` that does all the work in its constructor, and then provide a deduction guide, as shown in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548488/5481471).

You are [not the first](https://www.cppstories.com/2021/non-terminal-variadic-args/) to run into this issue, and it might be fixed in C++23, perhaps having the compiler automatically deduce the right thing, or maybe by allowing deduction guides for free functions.

## No need to connect two actions to the timer

Connecting two actions to the timer is not necessary. You could have the lambda quit the event loop, but even better is to only have the timer quit the event loop, and not set the variable `aborted`, but instead just check for `timer.isActive()` after the loop ended.

Comment: That's a neat trick with the deduction guide